# Mensaje en una etiqueta <p>

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Quiero mostrar un mensaje en una etiqueta

en un login que si el usuario no a ingresado ningún dato que muestre un mensaje de que no ha ingresado nada en esa etiqueta este es el código que estoy usando:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    var iniciar = document.getElementById('iniciarSesion');
    iniciar.addEventListener('click', function () {
        alert();
        var user    = document.getElementById('txtUsuario').value,
            pass    = document.getElementById('txtPass').value,
            msg     = "";


        if (user !== "" && pass !== "") {

        } else {
            msg = "alaal";
            document.getElementById('mensaje').value = msg;
        }

    });
}());
```

Se que necesito AJAX y eso pero quiero primero que me muestre el mensaje nada mas para empezar.

[image]

Este es el código del login

Apenas estoy iniciando en JavaScript

Comment: Bienvenido. En un caso como este sería conveniente que incluyeras un [mcve], en específico el HTML y JavaScript. Serían no más 20 líneas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacer lo que estas buscando, pero el concepto básico es la manipulación del DOM con JavaScript.

Si la estructura de tu página es estática, cuenta con una única etiqueta p o la de tu interés es la primera puedes usar `document.querySelector('p').innerHTML` ó `document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]`.

Si fuera otra la situación, hay una gran variedad de alternativas.

Ejemplo

```js
document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = '¡Hola mundo!';
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: Gracias Ruben me sirvio tu comentario logre hacer que mi mensaje apareciera deberas Gracias :D

Comment: Que bueno que te sirvió. Por favor lee: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

En el html puedes agregar la etiqueta p, con un id para llamarlo. Lo colocas donde quieres que aparesca.

```
<p id="mensaje"></p>
```

Para mostrar algún mensaje desde el script lo puedes cargar a su propiedad text.

```
document.getElementById("mensaje").text = "Mensaje en pantalla";
```

Y para que "desaparezca el mensaje" puedes cargarlo con vacío.

```
document.getElementById("mensaje").text = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer algo así, como mencionó @Aaron:

```js
 (function (){
  "use strict";
  const parrafo_de_error = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
  document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
   const usuario = document.getElementById("txtUsuario").value,
    pass = document.getElementById("txtPass").value;
   !usuario && !pass ? parrafo_de_error.textContent = "Escribe el usuario y contraseña" : parrafo_de_error.textContent = null;
  });
 })();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtUsuario">
<input type="password" id="txtPass">
<button>Iniciar Sesión</button>
<p style="color: red"></p>
```

Ocupar el operador ternario para hacerlo más corto `(condición) ? (true) : (false);`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer algo así, como mencionó @Aaron, y como el comentario de arriba, solo le estoy haciendo unas modificaciones ya que dijiste que estabas empezando en javascript

```js
var d = document,
  parrafo_de_error = d.getElementById("error");
d.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var usuario = d.getElementById("txtUsuario").value,
    pass = d.getElementById("txtPass").value;
  usuario !== "nombre_de_usuario" || usuario.length == 0 || pass !== "prueba" || pass.length == 0 ? parrafo_de_error.textContent = "Nombre de usuario y contraseña incorrecta" : parrafo_de_error.textContent = null;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtUsuario">
<input type="password" id="txtPass">
<button type="submit" id="enviar">Iniciar Sesión</button>
<p id="error" style="color: red"></p>
```

Ocupar el operador ternario para hacerlo más corto `(condición) ? (true) : (false);`

### **El Operador Ternario**

es una simplificacion de las condicionales if, else , solo que es mas simple y a su vez evalua condiciones solo evalua la condiciones de flaso y verdadero, las cuales son totalmentes requeridas en el if, else shortland

Answer (score 1):

Creo que con que cambies:

```
document.getElementById('mensaje').value = msg;
```

Por:

```
document.getElementById('mensaje').innerHTML = msg;
```

Sería suficiente para que te funcione ;)